# Does Date.parse work inside angular expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```js
function Ctrl($scope)
{
    $scope.dt = new Date('2012-07-16T00:00:00');
    var format = 
    {
     day: '2-digit',
      month: '2-digit',
      year: 'numeric'
    };
    $scope.dateTimeFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-es', format);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
In: {{dt}} <br/> 
Angular: {{dt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">
    This works: {{dateTimeFormatter.format(dt)}}
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:rgb(251, 123, 89);">
    This doesn't: {{dateTimeFormatter.format(Date.parse('2012-07-16T00:00:00'))}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Or why the green line works as expected, but the red one doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tries to find `Date` in scope ($scope.Date), and ofc found nothing.

Add

```
$scope.Date = Date;
```

and it'll work:

```js
function Ctrl($scope)
{
    $scope.dt = new Date('2012-07-16T00:00:00');
    var format = 
    {
     day: '2-digit',
      month: '2-digit',
      year: 'numeric'
    };
    $scope.dateTimeFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-es', format);
    $scope.Date = Date;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
In: {{dt}} <br/> 
Angular: {{dt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">
    This works: {{dateTimeFormatter.format(dt)}}
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:rgb(251, 123, 89);">
    This doesn't?: {{dateTimeFormatter.format(Date.parse('2012-07-16T00:00:00'))}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why my code then shows the current date? How I don't even get an error trying to find Date.parse method?

Comment: If Angular cannot evaluate expression, it replaces it with empty string. Without any errors. So, `{{dateTimeFormatter.format(Date.parse('2012-07-16T00:00:00'))}}` rendering in `{{dateTimeFormatter.format()}}`, which returns current date.

Comment: `{{dateTimeFormatter.format('')}}` returns "01/01/1970" but 
`{{dateTimeFormatter.format()}}` returns current date; does it returns an empty string or just undefined?

Comment: Sorry, it returns `undefined`, not empty string. `dateTimeFormatter.format(undefined)` returns current date, checked in console.

Comment: True!, [the spec says they are "forgiving"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angular-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions). Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how is that Date, a global javascript object, is not found by the angular expression?

Comment: @Razzka, no `Date.parse` can not return `undefined`. It can return a number or NaN.

Comment: @DavidDiez, it looking through `scope` object, not global. All references from `{{ }}` block leading to scope, so `{{Date}}` == `$scope.Date`

Comment: @k102, not `Date.parse`, it's tried to access `scope.Date.parse`, but `scope.Date` is undefined => `undefined.parse` returns undefined

Comment: And how is that `undefined.parse('2012-07-16T00:00:00')` doesn't throws an error?

Comment: @DavidDiez, You already mentioned that above, Angular is "forgiving": `expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null` and not throws errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dateTimeFormatter.format` expects a `Date` object - and you call it with `number`, since "The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC" (mdn).

Comment: `var dateTimeFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-es', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' });
dateTimeFormatter.format(Date.parse('2012-07-16T00:00:00'));
// returns on Firefox console "16/07/2016", why??`

Comment: `Date.parse` returns number, not a Date object